# Regex to Add a Character in a Space Pattern

Tags: regex

I have something like-

```
[[59],
[73 41],
[52 40 09],
[26 53 06 34],
[10 51 87 86 81],
[61 95 66 57 25 68]]
```

I need to add a comma before every space to be like -

```
[[59],
[73, 41],
[52, 40, 09],
[26, 53, 06, 34],
[10, 51, 87, 86, 81],
[61, 95, 66, 57, 25, 68]]
```

What would be regex string for that?

Comment: What language? Depending on the language a regex might be overkill.

Comment: I am using notepadd++ to add the commas..

Comment: So couldn't you just do a regular search and replace with a space for the search string and a " ," for the replace string?

Comment: I am learning REGEX. Like finding a match, a character in every line and so on.. But lost in this one..

Comment: I am a fan of learning, but one of the most important things about learning regexes is to learn when you should or should not use one.

Comment: @EBGreen I'd type that out as a regex replace in VIM in a heartbeat.

Comment: Well, that is because VIM only does regex replacements. That is not true of Notepad++ nor is it true of a lot of programming languages.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from your data, you may just replace a space ' ' by a comma followed by a space ', '. You do not need a regex for that.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what regex flavor you are using but in general, looking for matches would be

```
(\d+)\s
```

and replacing would be

```
\1,
```

Comment: What doesn't? The find or the replace? Note that the replace has a trailing space (I forgot to mention that in the answer)

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad++, open up the find control window with Ctrl+H.

- In **Find What** put a single space character
- In **Replace With** put a comma followed by a space character

This gives the expected output, but isn't very interesting as far as Regexes go.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/\( \)/,\1/g
```

And, as an afterthought:

```
s/ /, /g
```

Why bother with substitution replacement? :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(\d)\s(\d)` with
`\1, \2`